# `command not found` when using Bash Script to Install & Run a Software

Tags: bash, conda, anaconda3

I am trying to create a Bash script that downloads a `.sh` file, runs it to install a program (Anaconda for Python), then run the command `conda init` to activate the default Anaconda environment `base`

However, running my bash script as shown

```
# !#/bin/bash
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-*-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
echo 'export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
conda init
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

gives the error

```
./foo.sh: line 6: conda: command not found
./foo.sh: line 7: conda: command not found
```

Why is `conda` not found when trying to use it from within the Bash script, but is found if I relogin to the terminal?

How can we fix the Bash script so that using `conda` works?

Comment: Change `~/` to `$HOME` instead. Also try using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: While this isn't a Docker build, I think the Dockerfiles for things like [Miniconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/dockerfile) and [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge-images/blob/master/ubuntu/Dockerfile) are helpful references for good practices in how to bootstrap up a Conda installation. Also, I very much anti-recommend installing Anaconda - use a Miniforge or Miniconda installation. And you should not be adding `anaconda3/bin` to your PATH.

Comment: @Jetchisel This works! Just noticed that problem in `bashrc` when not using double quotes

Comment: Getting the warning message `IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.` when the script tries to run `conda init`

Comment: `conda init` configures a couple things for you, and modifies your `.bashrc`.  So you need to logout and login to ensure all the modifications are applied.  It is a warning, not an error.